# NetLogo static turtle

Tags: netlogo

I am new at NetLogo and I have been working on this assignment for school, and I can't seem to find an answer to one question. I do apologize if this has been answered somewhere else before.

I am trying to make two turtles. One turtle has to be moving around the area until it finds the second turtle, whereas the second turtle is staying still. I have been trying different things, and even used to wait time, but it worked for both turtles, which is not what I want.

How do I apply the code just to one turtle out of the two? And how do I make that turtle stay in one position?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you just use different [breeds](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/breed.html)?

Comment: Would that work even if I have just 2 turtles in total? How could I make one of them stay in way place, while the other walks around then?

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment- yes it works with any number of turtles if you like. For example:

```
breed [seekers seeker]
breed [waiters waiter]

to setup 
  ca
  reset-ticks
  create-seekers 1 [
    setxy random 30 - 15 random 30 - 15 
  ]
  create-waiters 1 [
    set shape "circle"
  ]
end

to go

  ask seekers [ 
    if not any? waiters in-radius 1 [
      rt one-of [ 90 0 -90]
      fd 1 
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

If you need them to be the same breed in your model, you can assign `turtles-own` variables to sort them however you like.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way, I can make waiters' position random every time I set up the simulation as well?

Comment: You bet. Try copying the line `setxy...` from the `create-seekers` block into the `create-waiters` block. That should do it!